# jQuery on hover out the element still retains the hovered class. This class styles should be removed when the mouse is hovered out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the login-btn to remain in its hover state when mouse is hovered over .login-content. I have already attempted at this, and for now it shows and hides the div on hover, but the login-btn loses its hover state when the .login-content is hovered, and the the .login-content disappears when it is hovered.

**Update:**

Current Issue is that the if the mouse is hovered over login and then directly hovered off.. instead of hovering over the child elements, the .hovered styles stays. This shouldnt be this way.

The HTML is as follows:

```
               <li><a href="#" class="login-btn">Login</a>
                    <div class="login-content">
                        <form name="login-form" action="" method="post">
                            <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-mail" />
                            <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
                            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="form-login" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

The jQuery code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".login-btn").hover(
   function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimeoutId'));
        $(".login-content").show();
        $(this).addClass('hovered');
    },
    function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimeoutId'));
        $(this).data('hoverTimeoutId', setTimeout(function () {

            $(this).removeClass('hovered');
            $(".login-content").hide();
        } ,500));
    });


$('.login-content').hover(
    function(){     
        clearTimeout($(".login-btn").data('hoverTimeoutId'));
    },     
    function(){    
        $(".login-content").hide();
        $(".login-btn").removeClass('hovered');
    });
});
```

The webpage can also be found at http://www.domainandseo.com/portfolio/1may/index.html if any further debugging is needed.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to *fade* it in or just have it pop up after 1 second?

Comment: just have it pop up after 1 second, and also disappear after 1 second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(".login-btn").hover(
    function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimeoutId'));
        $(".login-content").show();
        $(this).addClass('hovered');
    },
    function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimeoutId'));
        $(this).data('hoverTimeoutId', setTimeout(function () {
            $(".login-content").hide();
            $(this).removeClass('hovered');
        } ,500));
    });


$('.login-content').hover(
    function(){     
        clearTimeout($(".login-btn").data('hoverTimeoutId'));
    },     
    function(){    
        $(".login-content").hide();
        $(".login-btn").removeClass('hovered');
    });
```

Instead of using `:hover` psedoclass use a class like `hover` assign the hovered state to 
`login-btn` as shown in the demo

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6XDBE/2/)

Comment: This is pretty good. One more thing as stated in the question, that I would like to do is that when the .hover-content is hovered [or is visible], the .login-btn should in in its hover state.. having its black background and enhanced height. Any way to do this? Thanks again Arun.

Comment: @AlexZahir you need to change the css rule `.login-btn:hover` to `a.login-btn.hovered`

Comment: that is so much better. the only issue left now is that if the mouse is hovered over login and then directly hovered off.. instead of hovering over the child elements, the .hovered styles stays. This shouldnt be this way.

Comment: The above problem still exists but I'm accepting this answer as it still has helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout`

```
$(".login-btn").hover(
function() {
   clearTimeout($(this).data('animator'));
   $(this).data('animator', setTimeout(function () {
      $(".login-content").show();
   } ,1000));
},
function() {
   clearTimeout($(this).data('animator'));
   $(this).data('animator', setTimeout(function () {
      $(".login-content").hide();
   } ,1000));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uDm64/

Comment: this is great. but what about the second part of the question. As soon as I take the mouse off the login button and into the form inside it, the form disappears, and the login button loses its hover. I tried using the addclass which can be seen in the code given in the question, but it does not work.

Comment: @AlexZahir you could do this by only triggering the hiding if the `.hover` class is not present: http://jsfiddle.net/uDm64/1/

Comment: this code results in some glitches, like when any part of the header is hovered, the .login-content shows up. also, when the mouse is moved off, it does not hide, or hides after a very long delay even when lowering the timeout. Another important thing is that the hover state for the .login-btn is not turned on when the .login-content is in the hover state.

Comment: @AlexZahir I don't get some of what you mean but I think this should be an improvement: http://jsfiddle.net/uDm64/2/

Comment: I have updated the webpage at http://domainandseo.com/portfolio/1may/index.html with your code to let you know the prob. exactly. Even when the how it works button is hovered, the login button is shown. Also, the login button needs to retain its hovered state styles(it should have a black background) when the .hover-content items are hovered.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to worry about the user having the cursor away for a moment, then I would suggest a little more state checking.

Also, if you want your button to appear as hovered, in your CSS selector '.login-btn:hover', change it to: '.login-btn:hover, .login-btn.hover'

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qhAus/

```
(function() {
    var timer = 0,
        open = false,
        loginBtn = $('.login-btn'),
        loginContent = $('.login-content'),
        startTimeout = function(state, duration) {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                timer = 0;
                loginContent[state]();
                open = state === 'show';

                if(!open) {
                    // If it's closed, remove hover class
                    loginBtn.removeClass('hover');
                }
            }, duration || 1000);
    };

    loginBtn.hover(function(e) {
        $(this).addClass('hover');

        if(open && timer) {
            // If about to close but starts to hover again
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }

        if(!(open || timer)) {
            // Don't start to open again if already in the process
            startTimeout('show');
        }
    }, function() {
        // When not hovering anymore, hide login content
        startTimeout('hide', 2000);
    });

    loginContent.mousemove(function(e) {
        // If cursor focus on the login content, stop any closing timers
        if(timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    });

    loginContent.mouseleave(function(e) {
        // When cursor leaves login content, hide it after delay
        startTimeout('hide');
    });

})();
```